# passing an int to a function expecting an enumerated datatype

Tags: c++, arduino

For an arduino project, I am trying to use a library which contains code like this.

```
typedef enum
    {
      NOT_SPECIFIED = 0,
      MALE    = 1,
      FEMALE    = 2
    } gender;
```

and there is a function

```
void findCustomer(const char* userName, gender g);
```

In my own code where I let users input these info through a web interface, I save the gender entry as an int. Later, I want call `findCustomer` but if I pass an int as the second argument it gives me an error. To solve this, what is the dataType I should use to save the customer input so I can pass it on to `findCustomer`

Comment: `int i, switch(i)` to make a selection.

Comment: Yes you can use switch or use static_cast<gender>(1)  if you are sure valuse passed is (0,1,2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the dataType I should use to save the customer input so I can pass it on to findCustomer

You can use `static_cast` to cast your second argument from `int` to `enum` which should satisfy `findCustomer` prototype, something like this:

```
findCustomer( userName, static_cast<gender>(int_argument) )
```

Comment: @frarugi87 even that C style cast works, C++ style cast is always preferred

Comment: @artm true, even if the reasons for this preference is more important in PC applications than in small programs like arduino ones (if the programmer knows what he is doing...)